# How to listen for a layer zoom event in Polymaps?

Tags: javascript, maps, zooming, layer, polymaps

I'm using **Polymaps.js** library for making maps.
It would be very useful to be able to observe zoom level changes on layers. I'm trying to keep a layer of points scaled by values in meters, so I need to recalculate the radii whenever the zoom level changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the on "move" function, which I think is triggered on zooms, too. There may be on on "zoom" function, too. I think that there is.

For example:

```
// whenever the map moves...
map.on("move", function() {
    // get the current zoom
    var z = map.zoom();
    // show/hide parcels
    parcels.visible(z >= 16);
});
```